# CloudFront reverting TLS v1.2 to lower

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I can't get my CloudFront distribution to upgrade the cipher protocol and suites to TLS v1.2_2018. CloudFront will revert back the changes to TLSv1. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Check the `Last Modified` timestamp of the distribution, itself.  Is it changing, even though you didn't change anything?

Comment: I checked, and the last modified was by me. Definitely this changes made internally by AWS